# group by with multiple colums

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have one stuff in one table (A) and category of it in two others (C1,C2)
category_id coming from different table (MC).

I would like to count how many stuffs presented in particular category.

Example of live data:

table A

```
main_key (unique)    stuff_id (non unique)
   1                    7
   2                    6 
   3                    3
```

table C1

```
category_id main_key (it is FK for A table)
   1             1
   1             2
   3             1
```

table C2

```
category_id main_key (it is FK for A table)
   2             3
   2             1
```

table MC

```
category_id category_name
   1             blablbl
   2               asas
   3             asasa
...
```

relation between: 
C1 and A as many to one
C2 and A as many to one
C1 or C2 and MC as many to one

In current example I would like to see final result as

```
stuff_qnt        category_id        category_name
2                   1                  blablbl
2                   2                   asas
1                   3                   asasa
```

how I can achieve it with one single query ?

my query is:

```
SELECT count(A.stuff_id) as stuff_qnt, MC.category_id, MC.category_name 
FROM A
LEFT JOIN C1 using(main_key)
LEFT JOIN C2 using(main_key)
LEFT JOIN MC ON (C1.category_id = MC.category_id AND C2.category_id = MC.category_id)
GROUP BY C1.category_id, C2.category_id
```

But it shows me wrong result, what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Stuff_Qnt, C.Category_ID, MC.Category_Name
  FROM MC
  JOIN (SELECT C1.Category_ID
          FROM A
          JOIN C1 ON A.Main_Key = C1.Main_Key
        UNION ALL
        SELECT C2.Category_ID
          FROM A
          JOIN C2 ON A.Main_Key = C2.Main_Key
       ) AS C
    ON C.Category_ID = MC.Category_ID
 GROUP BY C.Category_ID, MC.Category_Name
 ORDER BY C.Category_ID, Stuff_Qnt;
```

You need the categories from joining A with C1 and the categories from joining A with C2, and you definitely don't want a Cartesian product such as you'd get with LEFT OUTER JOIN, so you take the UNION of the lists of category IDs, and then aggregate and join with MC.

```
CREATE TABLE A
(
    main_key INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    stuff_id INTEGER NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO A VALUES(1, 7);
INSERT INTO A VALUES(2, 6);
INSERT INTO A VALUES(3, 3);

CREATE TABLE MC
(
    category_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    category_name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO mc VALUES(1, "blablbl");
INSERT INTO mc VALUES(2, "asas");
INSERT INTO mc VALUES(3, "asasa");

CREATE TABLE C1
(
    category_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES mc,
    main_key INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES a
);
INSERT INTO c1 VALUES(1, 1);
INSERT INTO c1 VALUES(1, 2);
INSERT INTO c1 VALUES(3, 1);

CREATE TABLE C2
(
    category_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES mc,
    main_key INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES a
);
INSERT INTO c2 VALUES(2, 3);
INSERT INTO c2 VALUES(2, 1);

SELECT COUNT(*) AS Stuff_Qnt, C.Category_ID, MC.Category_Name
  FROM MC
  JOIN (SELECT C1.Category_ID
          FROM A
          JOIN C1 ON A.Main_Key = C1.Main_Key
        UNION ALL
        SELECT C2.Category_ID
          FROM A
          JOIN C2 ON A.Main_Key = C2.Main_Key
       ) AS C
    ON C.Category_ID = MC.Category_ID
 GROUP BY C.Category_ID, MC.Category_Name
 ORDER BY C.Category_ID, Stuff_Qnt;
```

Output:

```
2   1   blablbl
2   2   asas
1   3   asasa
```

---

Here is a further test with two extra rows in A, and corresponding rows in C1 and C2.  There are two queries tested, mine and the [query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13840710/15168) by [dkkumargoyal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1053633/dkkumargoyal).

```
CREATE TABLE A(main_key INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, stuff_id INTEGER NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO A VALUES(1, 7);
INSERT INTO A VALUES(2, 6);
INSERT INTO A VALUES(3, 3);
INSERT INTO A VALUES(4, 3);
INSERT INTO A VALUES(5, 3);

CREATE TABLE MC(category_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, category_name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO mc VALUES(1, "blablbl");
INSERT INTO mc VALUES(2, "asas");
INSERT INTO mc VALUES(3, "asasa");

CREATE TABLE C1(category_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES mc, main_key INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES a);
INSERT INTO c1 VALUES(1, 1);
INSERT INTO c1 VALUES(1, 2);
INSERT INTO c1 VALUES(3, 1);
INSERT INTO c1 VALUES(3, 4);
INSERT INTO c1 VALUES(1, 4);
INSERT INTO c1 VALUES(1, 5);

CREATE TABLE C2(category_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES mc, main_key INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES a);

INSERT INTO c2 VALUES(2, 3);
INSERT INTO c2 VALUES(2, 1);
INSERT INTO c2 VALUES(2, 5);

SELECT COUNT(*) AS Stuff_Qnt, C.Category_ID, MC.Category_Name
  FROM MC
  JOIN (SELECT C1.Category_ID
          FROM A
          JOIN C1 ON A.Main_Key = C1.Main_Key
        UNION ALL
        SELECT C2.Category_ID
          FROM A
          JOIN C2 ON A.Main_Key = C2.Main_Key
       ) AS C
    ON C.Category_ID = MC.Category_ID
 GROUP BY C.Category_ID, MC.Category_Name
 ORDER BY C.Category_ID, Stuff_Qnt;

-- Query by dkkumargoyal
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT A.stuff_id) AS stuff_qnt, MC.category_id, MC.category_name 
FROM A
LEFT JOIN C1 on a.main_key = c1.main_key  -- USING(main_key)
LEFT JOIN C2 on a.main_key = c2.main_key  -- USING(main_key)
LEFT JOIN MC ON (C1.category_id = MC.category_id OR C2.category_id = MC.category_id)
GROUP BY MC.category_id, mc.category_name
ORDER BY MC.Category_id, stuff_qnt;       -- stuff_qnt added for standard compatibility
```

The changes made were necessary for the code to work on the test DBMS (Informix 11.70.FC6).

Results 1:

```
4   1   blablbl
3   2   asas
2   3   asasa
```

Results 2:

```
3   1   blablbl
2   2   asas
2   3   asasa
```

I think my result is correct and the other not, mainly because the alternative depends on `A.Stuff_ID` being unique when the question stipulates that it is not unique (and the additional rows of data make it non-unique).

Comment: What do you think about query from `bonCodigo` ? and thank you for your help, I'm just thinking which one is better, his query a bit faster (i guess because less join used). Just interesting your thoughts. Thanks.

Comment: His query is pretty much equivalent to mine; he does a simpler (unjoined) UNION — it is arguably neater than mine which repeats the joining.  A really good optimizer might treat the two equivalently.  It's a good reorganization; if I'd spent longer working on it, I might have done the same.  It's a simple application of the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle.  His answer points to a way for you to simplify your life; do away with the two category tables; use just one.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this reference:

- [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/47045/2)

Query:

```
select m.category_id, m.category_name, count(a.stuff_id) as cntstuff from
(select * from c1 
 union all
 select * from c2) as c
join a 
on a.main_key = c.main_key
join mc m
on m.category_id = c.category_id
group by m.category_id
order by m.category_id
;
```

Results:

```
CATEGORY_ID     CATEGORY_NAME   CNTSTUFF
1               blablbl         2
2               asas            2
3               asasa           1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this SQL.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT A.stuff_id) AS stuff_qnt, MC.category_id, MC.category_name 
FROM A
LEFT JOIN C1 USING(main_key)
LEFT JOIN C2 USING(main_key)
LEFT JOIN MC ON (C1.category_id = MC.category_id OR C2.category_id = MC.category_id)
GROUP BY MC.category_id
```

Comment: On the sample data, this produces the desired result.  However, if you augment the sample data with: `INSERT INTO A VALUES(4, 3);
INSERT INTO A VALUES(5, 3); INSERT INTO c1 VALUES(3, 4);
INSERT INTO c1 VALUES(1, 4); INSERT INTO c1 VALUES(1, 5);
INSERT INTO c2 VALUES(2, 5);`, then this query produces a different result from mine as it depends on `A.Stuff_ID` being unique when the question stipulates that it is not (and the additional data makes it non-unique).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler What your SQL gives count of distinct A.main_key. that can easily be achieved from my query by using count(distinct A.main_key). However which query is write depends on the outcome user1016265 wants. My guess is based on the coulum selected in the question.